# Display multiple tooltips at once

Tags: tooltip

Is there any way to display multiple tooltips, or something similar to them? Overlays wont work because i need to display them using xy coordinates.

Comment: It’s not clear what you trying to do. What do you want a tooltip on, why are there multiple ones, etc. if you knew xy coordinates can you compute a tooltip?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I simply want to display multiple tooltips at once, that's it. Say 1 tooltip at x50 y50, another at x150 y150 coordinates.

Comment: But what should trigger that? Mousing over any of those points?  And how do you know what should be in the tooltips, does it depend on what is at the point? What is at the point?

Comment: Tooltips are usually associated with text, why do you need x,y coordinates?

Comment: I would trigger them with function. I would use them on pdf-tools buffer, this is why i can't use overlays and similar stuff, and why I need xy coordinates. I checked that tooltips are displayed using c function - x-show-tip, so there's probably no way to do this without writing new c func.